# issue with hashmap<string, marker>

Tags: android, dictionary

I have added a marker into hashmap by referring to a string key

```
HashMap<String,Marker> mapMarker = new HashMap<String,Marker>();
Marker marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
participantMarker.put(participantNumber,marker);
```

where user should be able to remove the marker from the map by input the matched key

```
Marker targetMarker = participantMarker.get(participantNumber);
targetMarker.remove();
```

but the problem is the marker wont get removed.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove using the key.

```
participantMarker.remove(participantNumber)
```

No need to get the value and then to remove by value.

Btw,

```
targetMarker.remove();
```

is not removing targetMarker from the HashMap, maybe 
you're confused here too and think it is doing so.

Comment: sorry for any confusing, but what i intended to do is remove the marker from the map

Comment: No need to be sorry, just check if the suggestions here work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this way:

```
participantMarker.remove(participantNumber);
```

Comment: i'm not intended to remove the marker from hashmap but from the map.